# Wrong position of visible signature

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a problem with placing a visible signature to an existing PDF. The problem occurs only with certain PDF. The code to calculate it appears to be fine. With the rotation of pages I've experimented, did not help. Trying java iText version 5.5.5.

Thumbnail of wrong output is [here](http:///www.quarim.cz/custom/itext/signed.png).

Pdf files is [here](http://www.quarim.cz/custom/itext/pdffiles.zip).

Log of the wrong output, files source.pdf and target.pdf:

```
page width = 1683.6
page height = 1205.52
image width = 240.0
image height = 160.0
ll = 1433.6, 10.0
ur = 1673.6, 170.0
```

Log of the correct output, files source2.pdf and target2.pdf:

```
page width = 1190.52
page height = 842.04
image width = 240.0
image height = 160.0
ll = 940.52, 10.0
ur = 1180.52, 170.0
```

What is wrong in a first pdf file? Can I add something to the java code that prevents this? Or is it iText bug?
Thanks for the tips.

Source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {

    String inputfilepath = "D:/temp/itext/source2.pdf";
    String outputfilepath = "D:/temp/itext/target2.pdf";
    String imagefilepath = "D:/temp/itext/signature.png";
    String ksfilepath = "D:/temp/itext/keystore.ks";
    String kspass = "kspass ";
    String keyalias = "keyalias";
    String keypass = "keypass";

    //get input pdf file
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputfilepath);

    //get keystore
    KeyStore ks = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        System.out.println("KeyStoreException exception: \n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksfilepath), kspass.toCharArray());
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        System.out.println("Certificate exception: \n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException: \n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //get key and certificate
    PrivateKey key = null;
    try {
        key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(keyalias, keypass.toCharArray());
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("Bad password for keystore given");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        System.out.println("KeyStoreException exception: \n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException: \n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Certificate[] chain = null;
    try {
        chain = ks.getCertificateChain(keyalias);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        System.out.println("KeyStoreException exception: \n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //set output pdf file
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);

    //get iText pdf stamper
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0', null, true);

    //set appearance of stamp
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setReason("sign test");
    appearance.setLocation("");

    //compute coordinates, margin 10 pt, position right down
    Rectangle pagesize;
    if (reader.getPageRotation(1) == 90 || reader.getPageRotation(1) == 270) {
        pagesize = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    } else {
        pagesize = reader.getPageSize(1);
    }
    Image image = Image.getInstance(imagefilepath);
    float llx = pagesize.getWidth() - image.getWidth() - 10;
    float lly = 10;
    float urx = pagesize.getWidth() - 10;
    float ury = image.getHeight() + 10;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
    System.out.println("page width = " + pagesize.getWidth());
    System.out.println("page height = " + pagesize.getHeight());
    System.out.println("image width = " + image.getWidth());
    System.out.println("image height = " + image.getHeight());
    System.out.println("ll = " + llx + ", " + lly);
    System.out.println("ur = " + urx + ", " + ury);

    //graphic
    appearance.setSignatureGraphic(Image.getInstance(imagefilepath));
    appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(rect, 1, null);

    //signature
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    String digestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
    CryptoStandard subfilter = null;
    ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(key, digestAlgorithm, provider.getName());
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);

    //write pdf and close streams
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    fout.close();

    System.out.println("File '" + inputfilepath + "' was succesfully signed and saved to '" + outputfilepath + "'");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText adds the signature at the correct position; that is: at the position you have chosen. However, you aren't choosing that position wisely.

Please take a look under the hood of source2.pdf:

[image]

We see that the visible area of the page is defined using the `/MediaBox` entry of the page dictionary. The lower-left corner of the page has the coordinates `x = 0; y = 0` and the upper-right corner of the page has the coordinates `x = 842.04; y = 1190.52`. Because the lower-left coordinates are `0, 0`; the coordinates of the upper-right corner correspind with `x = width; y = height`.

Now let's take a look at source.pdf:

[image]

In this PDF, the lower-left corner of the page has the coordinates `x = 0; y = -1205.52002` (or `x = 0; y = -height`) and the upper-right corner of the page has the coordinates `x = 1683.59998; y = 0` (or `x = width; y = 0`).

If you define your rectangle like this:

```
float llx = pagesize.getWidth() - image.getWidth() - 10;
float lly = 10;
float urx = pagesize.getWidth() - 10;
float ury = image.getHeight() + 10;
```

Then you are making the assumption that the lower-left corner is always `x = 0; y = 0` and that the upper-right corner is always `x = width; y = height`. This isn't necessarily true.

This is explained in the official documentation, see for instance:

- [Where is the origin (x,y) of a PDF page?](http://itextpdf.com/question/where-origin-xy-pdf-page)
- [How to position text relative to page?](http://itextpdf.com/question/how-position-text-relative-page)

You need to adapt your code like this:

```
float llx = pagesize.getRight() - image.getWidth() - 10;
float lly = pageSize.getBottom() + 10;
float urx = pagesize.getRight() - 10;
float ury = pageSize.getBottom() + image.getHeight() + 10;
```

If you examine the screen shot of source.pdf carefully, you'll also see that there's a `/CropBox`. This is an optional page boundary (you don't see a `/CropBox` in the source2.pdf). If it's present, you should take that page boundary to define `llx`, `lly`, `urx`, and `ury` because the `/CropBox` defines the visible area of the page. (In source.pdf, the `/CropBox` and the `/MediaBox` were identical, so it doesn't really matter in that case, but you should always check for the presence of a `/CropBox` entry first.)

Comment: Furthermore, the crop box should be used instead of the media box; not a problem in case of the sample documents (where the crop box coincides with the media box) but for other documents for sure.

Comment: Bruno, thank you very much for your quick response and detailed explanation. Your code works great. Thank you once again.